# Is there a way to fix the x axis (time) in a certain range in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to set my x axis between 6:00 am to next day 6:00 am,however when I try to customize the x axis, it gives range for a certain date. 
Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this, assuming you have a calendar dimension table which is in date-time format (i.e. not one dimDate and one dimTime).

In your calendar, create a calculated column:

```
AltDate = 
AltDate = 
IF(
    [Hour] < 6;
    [Date]-1;
    [Date]
)
```

Then, using the datetime column from the calendar as the x-axis in your visual and using the AltDate as the date slices you can force the range to be 6am to 6am, as seen below (the x-axis in the picure has a 5-minute resulution).
[image]